# Can't Click After Login on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse

Since I upgraded to 12.04 in April, I have had mouse issues.

- When I first log in, my mouse works fine (i.e. I can click and launch an application, or click-and-drag on the desktop).
- After I launch an application, for the most part I can no longer click on anything.  *Sometimes* I can click the title bar at the top (time, sound, etc. in the task bar).
- My keyboard still seems to work.  I can <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, or tab through widgets.

This happens for me on every single log in.  To fix the problem, I have to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, then log out, then log back in.  After that, my mouse works fine.

Is there anything like xprop or xwininfo that can tell me what has stolen my mouse? evtest still shows the mouse events - the desktop simply doesn't respond.  Does anyone have any solutions for this?  It seems similar to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/41301, but it's not "sporadic".

Comment: I still get this problem occasionally, apparently at random times. It doesn't happen frequently, though.

Comment: I have this problem every minute or so using Ubuntu 15.10. For me, the workaround is CTRL-ALT-DEL and then ESC (so I cancel the logout).

Answer (score 3):

See [After login, mouse not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182566/after-login-mouse-not-working/184644#184644)

> The manual workaround for me is to switch to the text console with `ctrl+alt+f1` and go back to X11 with `ctrl+alt+f7`.
>
> This magically reinitialize the mouse :-)

Comment: @avejidah If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you update your system regularly? I dont usually update my packages, but I was having issues, so I updated just the packages related to unity, and the problems are gone; I had some freezes of the system, now it is working better.

I know this is not a specific answer, but as you didnt say you have your system updated, thats my guess..