# After login, mouse not working!

Tags: mouse

I installed ubuntu 12.04 x64 on my PC. A short time after I login the mouse pointer disables and I can't move it!
Please help me, I am new in Linux.

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!** Do you have a labtop? Have you tried to use a USB mouse?

Comment: This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 6):

I have a similiar experience on a HP 2760p Elitebook after reboot.

The manual workaround for me is to switch to the text console with `ctrl+alt+f1` and go back to X11 with `ctrl+alt+f7`.

This magically reinitialize the mouse :-)

Comment: I have the exact same problem and your workaround helps me, too - but there has to be a better solution =(. I have this problem with two completely different computers, the only thing they have in common is the mouse, which is a R.A.T 5, but I doubt that it has something to do with the mouse

Comment: Seems that this bug is still going on, happens with my R.A.T. and with a w/e dell hp USB mouse on another machine. Only common factor I see at this point is USB and Ubuntu.

Comment: I have this issue with dell latitude touch pad, where i can move the mouse but unable to left click on anything! ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem on my Toshiba Satellite C660-1HE laptop. So instead of installing 64 bit, i tried installing 32-bit and now it is working fine.