# Can't Left Click After Plugging In Cyborg R.A.T. 9 Mouse

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I have a Cyborg R.A.T 9 mouse and when ever I plug it into my computer, I can't left click. Strangely enough, the mouse works fine at the login screen, but not after I log in. I'm also not able to alt+tab to other programs.

I've looked through the other questions for the R.A.T. 3, 5, and 7 mouses, but none of them have solutions that work.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 on a Lenovo ThinkPad T520.

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/184644/12864) help? (note that after you press the first key combination your desktop disappears, so **read ahead and know what the second one is** since that brings it back)

Comment: Nope :( It doesn't change anything...